# Linux csh script going to Suspended (tty output) when running with & (bg)

Tags: java, linux, shell

i have strange behavior i have csh file that run java process something like this :

run_server.csh

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

java -Dtest=testparam -cp ${TEST}/lib/device.jar:${TEST}/conf:${TEST}/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar  com.device.server
```

when i run it like this :
run_server.csh& in the putty shell in linux 
im getting this massage :

```
[2]  + Suspended (tty output)        run_server.csh
```

Although when i run it without the ampersand the server is running and outputting its log massages into the stdout but the problem is when i press ctr+c the process is killed

another strange thing is if i write wrapper script to run_server.csh
that looked like this run_server_wrapper.csh:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh 
run_server.csh &
sleep 5
```

it does run the server as bg process and the run_server_wrapper.csh it self 
getting the massage :

```
[2]  + Suspended (tty output)        run_server_wrapper.csh
```

what is the problem here ?

Comment: Perhaps you have a genuine reason to run `tcsh` but I would strongly recommend that you switch to Bash or some other Bourne-compatible shell.

Answer (score 6):

What's happening is that you're putting the process in the background, but it's still writing to the terminal. The terminal driver doesn't approve of that sort of behavior, and suspends the process when it tries to write to the TTY. The obvious answer, of course, is to stop doing that. If you're putting `run_server.csh` into the background, you should also redirect the output, like so:

```
run_server.csh > /path/to/serverlog 2>&1 &
```

If you want the program to run in the background and you still want to see the output, the usual solution is to redirect the output to a log file as I showed, and then monitor the log file with the `tail` command.

```
tail -f /path/to/serverlog
```

If you really, *really* want to have something running in the background and still able to write to the TTY, turn off the `tostop` flag.

```
stty -tostop
```

Answer (score 1):

One addition to [This isn't my real name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171689/this-isnt-my-real-name)'s useful answer:

If the process you put into the background needs user input, then it will be suspended until you provide input.